# R - How to tell which element does not exist in a list

Tags: r

```
l<-list(a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4)
```

Given a vector of names, I want to tell which `l[[name]]` does not exist. For example, given input `c("a","b")`, the output should be `F,F`. For input `c("a","e")`, the output should be `F,T`. My current code is `is.na(names(l[c("a","e")]))`. Are there better ways?

Comment: `!c("a", "e") %in% names(l)`

Comment: Depending on what exactly you're doing, set operations might be helpful too - `?setdiff` for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways one could do this. One way is shown by @chinsoon12.

Another way is using `grepl`. We can get the output of not matching names by negating the output of `grepl`.

```
!grepl(paste0(names(l), collapse = "|"), c("a", "b"))
#[1] FALSE FALSE

!grepl(paste0(names(l), collapse = "|"), c("a", "e"))
#[1] FALSE  TRUE
```